# Why is requests.get() retrieving different HTML using Python than browser?

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping

I am attempting to extract data from an HTML table, but it appears that the HTML isn't loading correctly when using `requests.get()`. Instead, a line in the source reads:

> "JavaScript is not enabled and therefore this page may not function correctly."

When I navigate to the page in Google Chrome, the HTML appears as it should.

How do I get a Python script to load the proper HTML?

Comment: It's most likely retrieving the exact same HTML. It's just that in the browser, Javascript runs and hides this line or replaces this line with something else.

Comment: Have you solved the problem? Has any of the answers helped?

Answer (score 9):

Welcome to the wonderful world of web-crawling. The problem you are experiencing is that `requests.get()` would just get you the initial page that the browser receives at the beginning of a page load. But, this is not the page you see in the browser since there could be so much involved in forming the web page: javascript function calls, AJAX calls etc.

If you want to programmatically get the HTML you see when you click "Show source" in a web browser after the page was loaded - you would need a real browser. This is there [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) could be a good option:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)
print browser.page_source
```

Note that `selenium` itself is very powerful in terms of [locating elements](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html) - you don't need a separate HTML parser for extracting the data out of the page.

Hope that helps.

Comment: is `selenium` the only option for such situation when need to enable JavaScript?

Comment: @DmitriyFialkovskiy nope, there are other options as well, for instance: things like "splash" JS engine, using browser developer tools and then requests to mimic the ajax/xhr calls on the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you have to deal with JavaScript, webdriver will handle better and saves your life.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://yourwebsite.com/html-table")
browser.find_element_by_id("some-js-triggering-elem").click()
while 1:
    try:
        browser.find_element_by_id("elem-that-makes-you-know-that-table-is-loaded")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        sleep(1)
html = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*").get_attribute("outerHTML")
# Use PyQuery or something else to parse the html and get data from table
```