# Parsing a table - getting NoneType error when the table exists

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

There are a few questions on parsing tables, which have been used here but the result is an error. My script is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = requests.get('http://www.asx.com.au/asx/statistics/prevBusDayAnns.do')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'contenttable announcements'})
table_body = table.find('tbody')
for rows in table_body.find_all('tr'):
    for cols in rows.find_all('td'):
        print cols
```

I have tried find_all and findAll but neither work. I've also checked and there is not more than one table so it shouldn't have any confusion.

Is anyone able to offer any insight here?

Cheers

Comment: Do `print(page.text)`. You will see you are getting `Please enable JavaScript to view the page content.` as a response

Comment: I've not come across this one before? Any way around it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23977040/why-is-requests-get-retrieving-different-html-using-python-than-browser