# Why is Beautiful Soup not printing out the text from a website (Reuters), even though the text is clearly there on the website?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping the date from this website: https://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-banks-conference-jpmorgan/jpmorgan-ceo-dimon-sees-u-s-economic-expansion-continuing-idUSKCN1IX508

When I try to get the date that is in the header/grey text area, the date is not getting printed.

```
page = requests.get("https://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-banks-conference-jpmorgan/jpmorgan-ceo-dimon-sees-u-s-economic-expansion-continuing-idUSKCN1IX508")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

headlines = soup.find_all('time')
for headline in headlines:
    headline_text = headline.get_text(strip=True)
    print("done:", headline_text)
```

This code outputs:

```
done: 
done: 
done: Updated
```

The image below shows that there is clearly text, but why isnt "June 1, 2018" getting printed out?

[image: pic of the webpage]

I've tried using html.parser and lxml, and both will not work.

Comment: Changing the parser to "html.parser" must work I think. Also, make sure you are getting 200 from the get() request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is requests.get() retrieving different HTML using Python than browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23977040/why-is-requests-get-retrieving-different-html-using-python-than-browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website is loaded dynamically, so `requests` doesn't support it. We can use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) as an alternative to scrape the page.

Install it with: `pip install selenium`.

Download the correct ChromeDriver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-banks-conference-jpmorgan/jpmorgan-ceo-dimon-sees-u-s-economic-expansion-continuing-idUSKCN1IX508"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"c:\path\to\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(URL)

# Wait for the page to fully render
sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.find_all("time"):
    print(tag.get_text(strip=True))

driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
June 1, 2018
9:21 AM
Updated 2 years ago
```

Comment: The original post had time as 14:21 for the article. However, the posted answer shows as 9:21 am.

Answer (score 1):

The site loads the content differently:

```
View Url is: https://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-banks-conference-jpmorgan/jpmorgan-ceo-dimon-sees-u-s-economic-expansion-continuing-idUSKCN1IX508
```

However, this loads the content dynamically but by using the developer tools ("Networks"), I was able to see that there is an instant-article URL path as well.

[image: The content of the url]

```
Actual Url to use: https://www.reuters.com/article/instant-article/idUSKCN1IX508
```

So, what must be done is to filter the last part from the View url that is `idUSKCN1IX508` and use it in the actual url to make the get() request. So, the changes are as follows:

```
page = requests.get("https://www.reuters.com/article/instant-article/idUSKCN1IX508")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")
soup.find_all("time")
Out[12]: 
[<time class="op-published" datetime="2018-06-01T14:21:41Z"></time>,
 <time class="op-modified" datetime="2018-06-01T14:19:02Z"></time>]
```

Furthermore, to get the time as text:

```
for item in obj_list:
    print("DateTime of the Article -- {}".format(item.get("datetime")))

DateTime of the Article -- 2018-06-01T14:21:41Z
DateTime of the Article -- 2018-06-01T14:19:02Z
```

Comment: thank you!! helpful to know that reuters has this instant article URL!

Comment: I am happy that this information has helped. Would you mind accepting this answer or any other answer which was helpful to you? It will provide help to people experiencing a similar issue and will help to get your question noticed. For more information, take a look at our [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Thanks and welcome to SO!